# How to implement a webpage login, using POSIX permissions on CentOS 7?

Tags: hash, md5, backend, salt, password-encryption

I am designing a storage appliance that runs on CentOS 7. For accessing storage, we are using the standard Linux POSIX permissions. For accessing the web based interface for managing the storage, we would like to use the same user name and password so that the user doesn't have to remember two. Everything is chugging along nicely, but there is one hole.

Quick architecture background: web based front end interfaces with appliance database, python service in back end watches database and takes action... feedback happens the same way.

The question: Where and how should I store the HASH and SALT for each user. Mainly a security and architecture question.

More information: Basically when the appliance starts the back end will parse the Linux passwd, group, and shadow files and plop the information into the database... is it okay to store the hash and salt in the database, or should that remain only in the shadow file (I think it would only be useful to store both and it would make programming easier, but are there security concerns)? I've heard you never want the server to know the actual password, but how would this work if you are also are supposed to hash at the server, not the client? i.e. the server will know the password for 1 line of code before it is hashed.

This is a question with common subjects, but optimizing authentication for this particular architecture is proving kind of confusing. A diagram is worth a thousand words if someone has done something similar.

[image]
The above diagram seems to show the minimum I intend to do. But this has concerns:

1. Password and user is transmitted to server over clear text.
2. Server will know password for a minute.
3. Database knows both the hash and salt.

These three concerns are what are stopping me from implementing this. I've already implemented variations many times, I want to get it right this time. Are my concerns warranted and how do I compensate?

Comment: You can do MD5 (and other) hashes in the browser with Javascript.  I've used [this surprisingly little library](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/) before, to get a username and password from a user, and a nonce from a server, hash them, and send the result back to the server (or something like that, I can't remember off-hand). That stops the password going over the wire.

Comment: I thought of that, the only problem really is that your client side [generated] hash becomes the password... but I'm not 100% sure what the implications of that are. From my research, I now know https will solve security flaw 1... I think it's what it was designed for. 2 & 3 I am still unsure of, but now I think 3 is the more critical one; might just come down to securing mysql. Someone out there has to be a web interface DB POSIX user management and security expert... anyone? lol

Comment: I may be misremembering the way PAM MD5 passwords work, but I'm suggesting that the server send the salt that it stores as part of the encrypted password, then the client encrypts `salt+password`, and sends that back. Then the server checks that that result matches what it has stored. This overall scheme has always depended on the server knowing the hash+salt. Doing the encryption in the browser means you're not relying on TLS confidentiality at all.